# How to setup SimpleHTTPServer with a DNS on Windows

Tags: python, windows, simplehttpserver

I am using the Python Module SimpleHTTPServer on a Windows machine. Is is possible to set it up so that you do not have to enter "*IP*:*PORT*...", but instead "*HOSTNAME*:*PORT*..."? Or is this a Windows thing?

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

class MyReqHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler) :
    def some_function(self) :
        ...

http_serv = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer(('', 8000), MyReqHandler)
http_serv.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Example please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself. It is indeed a Windows thing. I added "127.0.0.1" to the list of DNS Servers in the configuration of my network device.